# C - Can't stop program using while and logical operator

Tags: c

I'm just starting learning C but I really don't know what am I doing wrong. I wrote this code, and it was supposed to stop reading numbers when it receives a negative number. I have wasted a lot of time trying to figure out what it is wrong, and I still don't know what it is.

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main(){
    const int qtd = 3;

    float ent[qtd];
    int i = qtd;

    printf("Digite os numeros\n");

    do{
        scanf("%f", &ent[i]);
        i--;
    }while (ent[i] >= 0 && i >= 1);



    printf("\n\n\n\nPressione 'Enter' para sair");
    fflush(stdin);
    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Since the array has 3 elements, the valid indexes are 0,1, and 2. However, the first scanf is equivalent to `scanf("%f", &ent[3]);`. That cause undefined behavior, meaning that for example, you could be changing the value of `i`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is with the index of `ent` that you check for being negative. It's `ent[i]`, but it is *after* `i` has been decremented, so you are reading the location that has not been written yet by `scanf`.

To fix the problem, change the code to use the prior location, i.e.

```
do {
    ...
} while (ent[i+1] >= 0 && ...);
```

There are several other problems with your code, all coming from the assumption that array indexes start at `1`. In C, however, the initial index is zero, not one, so the correct check should be

```
do {
    ...
} while (ent[i+1] >= 0 && i >= 0);
```

In addition, `i` should be initialized to `int i = qtd-1;` to avoid writing past the end of allocated array.

Comment: @artm I was in the process of making an edit about that. OP seems to think that array indexes are 1..N, inclusive, not 0..N-1.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight Indeed I thought that the indexes were 1..N, but now I realize. I'll rewrite it.